Choosing customized outlook labels via PowerShell or any other scripts while sending new email
I have few customized labels in my organization and i want to use it when sending a new mail via PowerShell.
I did try the a method and found in the link Adding Unified Label to outgoing Outlook email via Powershell script and by this option i did try by adding GUID and the  GUID is something like 6851ce54-5483-42b7-9228-757e253b1d36 but when i try this with the code like - $mail.propertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{"My_GUID"}/msip_labels/0x0000001F", "My_Label");
this does not work, it still send mail with default Label.
Can some one please help ?
I did try the a method and found in the link Adding Unified Label to outgoing Outlook email via Powershell script and by this option i did try by adding GUID and the  GUID is something like 6851ce54-5483-42b7-9228-757e253b1d36 but when i try this with the code like - $mail.propertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{"My_GUID"}/msip_labels/0x0000001F", "My_Label");
Expecting to send Email via Powershell choosing the label which i want.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
